# How to output in a shell script to the console and on a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout, stderr

I have shell script in Linux like below

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_LOCATION=/home/$USER/logs
exec > >(tee /home/$USER/logs/"$1") 2>&1

[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }

table=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}


`hive -e "create table testing.${table} as select * from fishing.${table}"`

cp /home/$USER/logs/"$1" /home/$USER/debug/"$1" 

g_STATUS=$?
log_status $g_STATUS "Hive create ${table}"

echo "***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************"
```

If I have this in my shell script

```
exec 2>&1 | tee /home/logging/"$1"
```

Then I am getting logs only on console not on the redirected file.

If I have this in my script

```
exec> /home/logging/"$1" 2>&1
```

Then I am having logs on the redirected file but not on the console.

How can I have logs both on console and redirected file

Comment: What do you want to do? run $1?

Comment: Try including `unbuffer` before `exec` ...

Comment: @kabanus $1 is variable which I will pass to the script

Comment: Maybe this answer can solve your problem [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use process substitution with `exec` builtin:

```
exec > >(tee trace.log) 2>&1
```

to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file as as well as show it in terminal.

Comment: If I want to redirect only `stderr` logs when I do `exec 2> >(tee trace.log)` it is still doing output to `stdout`

Comment: I want like above question `stderr` to both console and redirected file. How can we achieve that?

Comment: `exec 2> >(tee trace.log)` works fine for me to redirect only stderr to file and terminal.

Comment: In the script if `stdout` is having failed message and when we collect the logs to a single file I am getting the job status as success. When the `stdout` has error message the job should show failed status while collecting the logs. `how can I do that`?

Comment: in the above script if i don't use `LOG_LOCATION=/home/$USER/logs
exec > >(tee /home/$USER/logs/"$1") 2>&1` these and if the job fails I will get the status message as failed. But if I use the `LOG_LOCATION=/home/$USER/logs
exec > >(tee /home/$USER/logs/"$1") 2>&1` then even if the job fails then I am getting job as success in the status logs

Comment: for hive to run in shell scripts we have to use backticks. The problem above is I am creating a table in hive using the script. If the table already exists the job will fail, but the status shows success when I am collecting the logs

Comment: Please create a new question with `hive` tag as I cannot reproduce your problem. Also try to remove reverse quotes around `hive` command.

Comment: I have posted another question which might give you a clear picture. Please have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528616/status-log-of-shell-script-shows-job-success-even-though-the-actual-job-fails`

Comment: Finally after many tests I found out the problem. Here in my script after the `hive` statement, I am doing cp /home/$USER/logs/"$1" /home/$USER/debug/"$1" . if I don't do the copy and if the `hive` statement fails then I get status as fail. If I do the copy even if the `hive` statement fails then I am getting status as success. Is there a way of getting around this. If the `hive` statement fails then I want status as failed. irrespective of what the script does after `hive` statement

Comment: In that case store `$?` in a variable right after `hive` command but before `cp` or any other command.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you Now after doing what you have suggested the `cp` after the status doesn't perform the action. I am not getting the logs to be copied to another location

Comment: In the script after these `g_STATUS=$?` `log_status $g_STATUS "Hive create ${table}"`, I have `cp /home/$USER/logs/"$1" /home/$USER/`
I just run the script like `./shell.sh tablename`

Comment: oh that is due to `exit 1` inside `log_status` function, which is exiting the script. Comment that out.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `tee` command is specifically intended to direct the output to both a file and to the terminal, which is what it sounds like you're wanting.  This can be replicated pretty easily with something like the following:

script.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
date 2>&1 | tee "$1"
```

Then, running the command with `./script.sh abc.txt` will produce the output of the date command to the terminal as well as the file `abc.txt`

In your case, `exec 2>&1 | tee /home/logging/"$1"` should correctly produce the results you want, but you will need to call the script with that argument carefully.  That assumes the `/home/logging` directory exists, and you call the script above with something like `./script log.txt`